# Using preconditioners efficiently

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I am trying to numerically solve a linear system of equations of the form

`A x = a`

where `A` is really ill-conditioned and `a` a vector. Both `A` and `a` are known and I need to determine `x`.

Such systems of linear equations arise when considering discretisations of PDEs using spectral collocation methods, for instance. In order to solve this problem, I am trying to use arbitrary precision and iterative methods that use preconditioners.

One such preconditioner, is to find a finite difference approximation to `A` and `a`, which I will denote by `B` and `b` respectively. I would like to know how to take advantage of this using Mathematica.

So far, my code looks like the following:

```
g = LinearSolve[B];
f = x \[Function] g[x];
solF = f[b];
LinearSolve[A, a, 
 Method -> {"Krylov", "Method" -> "BiCGSTAB", 
   "Preconditioner" -> f, "StartingVector" -> solF}]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Information is a bit rare here. In what form is `A` given? Is `A` a dense matrix, a sparse array` or only a function that implements matrix-vector multiplication?

Comment: ```A``` is really dense, but ```B``` is rather sparse.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the action of `A` on vectors without assembling it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there is no way that I know of implement the action of ```A``` on vectors...

Answer (score 3):

```
 SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve[A, a, 
   "Method" -> "BiCGSTAB", "Preconditioner" -> f, "StartingVector" -> solF
   ]
```

might get you rid of some calling overhead. But improving the quality of your preconditioner will have a considerably larger effect.

If `LinearSolve[B]` works as a preconditioner, then possibly its incomplete LU preconditioner might work as well. Since it is cheaper to apply then `LinearSolve[B]`, you should give it a try. If I recall it correctly, you have to set up this preconditioner as follows:

```
data = SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[B];
f = x \[Function] SparseArray`SparseMatrixApplyILU[data, x];
```

Note that this will work only if `B` is a sparse matrix.

If you manage to implement the action of `A` on vectors as a function `fA` so that `fA[x] == A.x`, then you can use `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve `` as follows

```
 SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve[fA, a, 
   "Method" -> "BiCGSTAB", "Preconditioner" -> f, "StartingVector" -> solF
   ]
```

This is useful for matrices whose `fA` action can be implemented without assembling `A`. If `A` is a dense matrix of size $N \times N$, then its assembly cost $O(N^2)$ time and memory and `A.x` costs $O(N^2)$ time. But if `A` stems from a convolution with a function, i.e. $A \, x = x * u$, then the fast Fourier transform can be employed to implement `fA` that computes `fA[x]` in $O(N \, \log(N))$ time.